# 64k connection myth and NAT translation

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, server

I have a lot (ten of thousands) of connected mobile devices which are maintaining an opened connection to a server. If my understanding of the 64k connection limitation is correct, you cannot have more than 64k (because of the TCP/IP protocol) connections to a single port of a server per client IP (because of the range of ephemeral ports on the client side).

But most of the time, you are in a context where these devices are connected through a network provider which use NAT to translate addresses. (for example, a smartphone won't have a static IP address).

So in this context, my server will see the same ip address and nothing garantee that the source port won't be the same in 2 different clients.

My question is maybe dumb but there it is : how can my server identify the correct connection if we think of a connection as the 5-tuple (protocol, server port, server ip, client ip, client port) in this situation ? Is there a risk of losing a connection or conflicts between 2 different clients ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my server will see the same ip address and nothing guarantees that the source port won't be the same in 2 different clients [...] Is there a risk of losing a connection or conflicts?

No, that's the job of the router performing the NAT: keeping the IP:port combinations at one side linked to the ones on the other side.

So:

```
Client | IP | Src | < NAT > | IP | Src | Dest   | Dst
====================================================== 
1      | .1 |  42 | <-----> | .3 |   1 | Server | 80 
2      | .2 |  84 | <-----> | .3 |   2 | Server | 80
```

Given two clients, with (source IP 10.0.0.1, source port 42) and (source IP 10.0.0.2, source port 84) wish to connect to your server at port 80, then NAT will translate their IP:port pair to a pair that is valid on the *other* (right) side of the NAT (e.g. 11.0.0.3), by giving them a unique source port (on *that* side of the NAT). It will keep this translation in memory in order to be able to send packets both ways.

You'll see that the tuples on the right side of the NAT (so what your server sees) are unique:

```
11.0.0.3:1 - Server:80 
11.0.0.3:2 - Server:80
```

If the router determines that the possible tuples towards your server have exhausted (so after `11.0.0.3:65535 - Server:80`), it may refuse to open new connections to it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks very clear answer. I imagine that network provider's NAT (mainly for mobile network type 2G/3G/4G) can handle this use case easily.

Comment: @jobou well one of the solutions is to let your NAT have multiple IP addresses on the right side. :) ISPs can do this just fine.